# Two families of sets $F$ and $G$ are disjoint iff for all $A∈F$ and $B∈G$, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $F$ and $G$ are families of sets. Prove that $F$ and $G$ are disjoint if and only if for all $A∈F$ and $B∈G$, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint

I am trying to work through this homework problem but I am having trouble getting past how to get started.  Could help with setting up this to prove?

I know I need to prove by contradiction and there is a biconditional statement so  need to prove this in two directions.

Answer (score 2):

False. Counterexample:
$$F=\{\emptyset\},\qquad G=\{\emptyset\}.$$
The true condition: $F$ and $G$ are disjoint iff forall $A\in F$, $B\in G$: $A\ne B$.

Comment: A nondegenerate example: $F = \{\{1,2\}\}$ and $G = \{\{1,3\}\}$. Then $F$ and $G$ are disjoint but don't satisfy the other condition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $F,G$ are *not* disjoint if they have a common element, which in this problem must be some set $S\in F\cap G$.

Comment: So, suppose ∪F and ∪G are disjoint. Suppose A∈F and B∈G and A and B are not disjoint.  Then there exists an x such that x∈A and x∈B.  Since x∈A and A∈F, then x∈∪F, and since x∈B and B∈G, then x∈∪G.  This proves there's a common element between F and G like you said, correct?